# Nginx only serving static files for a Sinatra application

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to run ruby (sinatra) script under the Nginx.
My folder structure is:

```
/www (775)
/www/public (775)
/www/public/img.jpg (644)
/www/app.rb (775)
/www/index.html (775)
```

My nginx.conf is:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  passenger_root /home/my_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/passenger-5.1.6;
  passenger_ruby /home/my_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/wrappers/ruby;

  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile        on;

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxx.xxx.xx.xx;

    root /www/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
  }
}
```

But I'm getting served just a *xxx.xxx.xx.xx/img.jpg*, no script.
*xxx.xxx.xx.xx/index.html* gives me error 404 and *xxx.xxx.xx.xx* gives me error 403 again.

Is important under which user is nginx server running (folder */www* and files inside it have a different user than the user running nginx).

Thanks

Comment: How does Ruby and Sinatra factor in here when you have a static `index.html`?

Comment: Well, even if I reneame it to test.html, it is not working anyway. Sinatra is serving such file on '/' get.

Comment: Unless you have a `config.ru` somewhere in there then Passenger has no way of knowing you have a Rack application.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!
I'm mostly running on Rails, so I forgot. Took me 3 hours, but thank you a lot!

Comment: Are you  using RBENV/RVM or just system ruby?

Comment: What does  "bundle exec passenger start" show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to @tadman the configuration was ok, the problem was just missing *config.ru* file.